# javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException: Unable to extract parameter from http request

Tags: java, web-services, rest, resteasy

well i created a restful webservice wi th a get method that returns a list of bank transactions based on an account id. the service works fine when i test.

Then i created a restful client in my managedBean. this exceptions pops out when i invoke my webservice.

i tried this method already with a list of all clients (without parameters) and it worked but when i add a parameter to my transactions method the id could not be extracted from my request.

this is my webservice

```
@Stateless
@Path("/transactions")
public class TransactionWebService {


    @EJB
    private GestionAccountsLocal local1;

    @EJB
    private GestionTransactionsLocal local2;


    @GET
    @Path("/{id}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<Transaction> getTransactionById(@PathParam(value="id") Integer id)
    {
        Account account=local1.findAccountByid(id);
        return local2.showTransactionByAccount(account);
    }
}
```

this is my restful client

```
import java.text.MessageFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.json.JsonException;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import org.json.JSONArray;



@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class WebServiceTransaction {

    private WebTarget webtarget;
    private Client client;
    private entities.Account account;
    private Transaction  transaction;
    private List<Transaction> transactions;
    private static final String base_url= "http://localhost:8383/ebankingWEB/rest/transactions" ;
    public WebTarget getWebtarget() {
        return webtarget;
    }
    public void setWebtarget(WebTarget webtarget) {
        this.webtarget = webtarget;
    }

    public Transaction getTransaction() {
        return transaction;
    }
    public void setTransaction(Transaction transaction) {
        this.transaction = transaction;
    }
    public static String getBaseUrl() {
        return base_url;
    }
    public Client getClient() {
        return client;
    }
    public void setClient(Client client) {
        this.client = client;
    }

    public WebServiceTransaction() {
        client= ClientBuilder.newClient();
        webtarget=client.target(base_url).path("id");
    }


    public List<Transaction> getTransactions() {
        return transactions;
    }
    public void setTransactions(List<Transaction> transactions) {
        this.transactions = transactions;
    }

    public List<Transaction> convertToList (String jsonListString) throws JsonException{
        try{
            JSONArray jsonList = new JSONArray(jsonListString);
         transactions = new ArrayList<Transaction>();
        for (int i=0 ; i < jsonList.length();i++){
            Transaction transaction = new Transaction(jsonList.get(i).toString());
            transactions.add(transaction);

        }
        return transactions;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            throw new JsonException(e.getMessage());
        }

        }

    public List<Transaction> getTransactionsByAccount (Integer id){
        try{

            WebTarget ressource = webtarget;
            ressource.path(MessageFormat.format("{0}" , new Object[]{id}));
            String jsonListString = ressource.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(String.class);
            return convertToList(jsonListString);
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                String message = "non existant transactions ";
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                        .addMessage(
                                null,
                                new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO,
                                        message, null));
                e.printStackTrace();
                return new ArrayList<Transaction>();

            }
        }
    public entities.Account getAccount() {
        return account;
    }
    public void setAccount(entities.Account account) {
        this.account = account;
    }
    }
```

and this is my log

```
15:51:05,177 WARN  [org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler] (default task-26) failed to execute: javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException: Unable to extract parameter from http request: javax.ws.rs.PathParam("id") value is 'id' for public java.util.List webServices.TransactionWebService.getTransactionById(java.lang.Integer)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.PathParamInjector$1.throwProcessingException(PathParamInjector.java:54) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.8.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.StringParameterInjector.extractValue(StringParameterInjector.java:336) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.8.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.PathParamInjector.inject(PathParamInjector.java:131) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.8.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.injectArguments(MethodInjectorImpl.java:89) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.8.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:112) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.8.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:296) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.8.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:250) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.8.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:237) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.8.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:356) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.8.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:179) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.8.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:220) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.8.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.8.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.8.Final.jar:]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:113) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:240) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:227) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:73) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:146) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:177) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:727) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "id"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
    at java.lang.Integer.<init>(Integer.java:677) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.StringParameterInjector.extractValue(StringParameterInjector.java:319) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.8.Final.jar:]
    ... 38 more

15:51:05,191 ERROR [stderr] (default task-25) javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException: HTTP 404 Not Found

15:51:05,191 ERROR [stderr] (default task-25)   at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.handleErrorStatus(ClientInvocation.java:181)

15:51:05,191 ERROR [stderr] (default task-25)   at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.extractResult(ClientInvocation.java:154)

15:51:05,191 ERROR [stderr] (default task-25)   at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.invoke(ClientInvocation.java:444)

15:51:05,192 ERROR [stderr] (default task-25)   at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocationBuilder.get(ClientInvocationBuilder.java:165)

15:51:05,192 ERROR [stderr] (default task-25)   at tn.esprit.webServiceData.WebServiceTransaction.getTransactionsByAccount(WebServiceTransaction.java:89)

15:51:05,192 ERROR [stderr] (default task-25)   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

15:51:05,192 ERROR [stderr] (default task-25)   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)

15:51:05,192 ERROR [stderr] (default task-25)   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

15:51:05,192 ERROR [stderr] (default task-25)   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)

15:51:05,193 ERROR [stderr] (default task-25)   at javax.el.ELUtil.invokeMethod(ELUtil.java:308)

15:51:05,193 ERROR [stderr] (default task-25)   at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:537)

15:51:05,193 ERROR [stderr] (default task-25)   at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:256)

15:51:05,193 ERROR [stderr] (default task-25)   at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:269)

15:51:05,193 ERROR [stderr] (default task-25)   at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)

15:51:05,193 ERROR [stderr] (default task-25)   at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)

15:51:05,194 ERROR [stderr] (default task-25)   at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)

15:51:05,194 ERROR [stderr] (default task-25)   at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)

15:51:05,194 ERROR [stderr] (default task-25)   at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)

15:51:05,194 ERROR [stderr] (default task-25)   at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)

15:51:05,194 ERROR [stderr] (default task-25)   at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)

15:51:05,194 ERROR [stderr] (default task-25)   at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)

15:51:05,194 ERROR [stderr] (default task-25)   at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)

15:51:05,195 ERROR [stderr] (default task-25)   at javax.faces.component.UIData.broadcast(UIData.java:1108)

15:51:05,195 ERROR [stderr] (default task-25)   at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)

15:51:05,195 ERROR [stderr] (default task-25)   at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)

15:51:05,195 ERROR [stderr] (default task-25)   at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)

15:51:05,195 ERROR [stderr] (default task-25)   at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)

15:51:05,195 ERROR [stderr] (default task-25)   at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)

15:51:05,196 ERROR [stderr] (default task-25)   at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)

15:51:05,196 ERROR [stderr] (default task-25)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)

15:51:05,196 ERROR [stderr] (default task-25)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61)

15:51:05,196 ERROR [stderr] (default task-25)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)

15:51:05,196 ERROR [stderr] (default task-25)   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)

15:51:05,196 ERROR [stderr] (default task-25)   at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25)

15:51:05,197 ERROR [stderr] (default task-25)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:113)

15:51:05,197 ERROR [stderr] (default task-25)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:56)

15:51:05,197 ERROR [stderr] (default task-25)   at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25)

15:51:05,197 ERROR [stderr] (default task-25)   at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45)

15:51:05,197 ERROR [stderr] (default task-25)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:61)

15:51:05,197 ERROR [stderr] (default task-25)   at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58)

15:51:05,198 ERROR [stderr] (default task-25)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70)

15:51:05,198 ERROR [stderr] (default task-25)   at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76)

15:51:05,198 ERROR [stderr] (default task-25)   at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25)

15:51:05,198 ERROR [stderr] (default task-25)   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)

15:51:05,198 ERROR [stderr] (default task-25)   at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25)

15:51:05,198 ERROR [stderr] (default task-25)   at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25)

15:51:05,198 ERROR [stderr] (default task-25)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:240)

15:51:05,198 ERROR [stderr] (default task-25)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:227)

15:51:05,198 ERROR [stderr] (default task-25)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:73)

15:51:05,198 ERROR [stderr] (default task-25)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:146)

15:51:05,198 ERROR [stderr] (default task-25)   at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:177)

15:51:05,198 ERROR [stderr] (default task-25)   at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:727)

15:51:05,198 ERROR [stderr] (default task-25)   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)

15:51:05,198 ERROR [stderr] (default task-25)   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)

15:51:05,198 ERROR [stderr] (default task-25)   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

PS:
i think this line is the issue since it gets the base url but the id is not extracted correctly  `webtarget=client.target(base_url).path("id");`

if you need anything else please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You configured your Service with

```
 @Path("/{id}")
```

So you should not mention the path fragment "/id" in your webtaregt in the constructor :

```
webtarget=client.target(base_url).path("id"); // wrong
webtarget=client.target(base_url); // OK
```

Ex : considering transaction id=1 exists, check on your webbrowser :

```
../transactions/id/1 //wrong
../transactions/1 // OK
```

Comment: thank you :) you are correct sir, i did that and i also added a line in my client that i forgot due to the stress lol. i'm going to post the answer.

Comment: yes indeed the WebTarget object works like a builder and you have to reassignate it with the retuning value of any of its methods.

Answer (score 0):

i corrected my rest client and it worked like a charm.

```
webtarget=client.target(base_url);
```

and

```
 WebTarget ressource = webtarget;
            ressource = ressource.path(MessageFormat.format("{0}" , new Object[]{id}));
```

before that , i didn't affect a ressource to my parameter.